# Вопрос от новичка в Unity3d/C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Здравствуйте уважаемые мастера геймдева, подскажите насчет юнити, как реализовать в 2д игре свайпы так, чтобы при нажатии на экран создавался к примеру огненный шар и затем его можно было метнуть во врага и нанести ему урон, хотя бы подскажите где и в каком направлении мне искать информацию? По типу игры "Wizard swipe"

Вот пока что есть:

```
void Update() {
Touch screenTouch = Input.GetTouch(0); 
if (screenTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
  transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, 
  new Vector3 (screenTouch.deltaPosition.normalized.x, 
  transform.position.y, transform.position.z) speed * Time.deltaTime); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: приведите код который вы пытались сделать

Comment: @Антон пока что только есть код позволяющий передвигать предмет, но не понимаю как отправить этот предмет в полёт.               void Update()
  {   
           if (Input.touchCount == 1)
            {
                Touch screenTouch = Input.GetTouch(0);

                if (screenTouch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
                                      
                  transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, new Vector3 (screenTouch.deltaPosition.normalized.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z) speed * Time.deltaTime);
                
     }
}